# Redirect into SilverStripe's pages

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to set up a redirect on my SilverStripe site.

I have created my own module, and now I want the user to be redirected to that after log in.

I've tried with `Director::redirect($Url_base . 'myModule')`, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Ed I think we need some more info to help you out.  Where is the module, front end or back end?  Are we talking different page types from the module, or a new admin interface?

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://www.ssbits.com/customize-the-redirect-after-a-successful-member-login/

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

```
class MyLoginForm extends MemberLoginForm {
    public function dologin($data) {
        parent::dologin($data);
        if (Director::redirected_to() && $Member = Member::currentUser()) {
            $this->controller->response->removeHeader('Location');
            if ($Member->Email == 'admin') {
                $destination = '/admin';
            } else {
                $destination = '/user/' . $Member->Username;
            }
            Director::redirect($destination);
        }
    }
}
```

If it is the admin user I redirect them to `/admin`. If it is another user I redirect them to `/user/username`.